# CircularGauge is missing in Qt6.2

Tags: qt, qtquick2

I have recently migrated to Qt6.2. However, I can't find QtQuickExtras and CircularGauge. Seems they are missing and can't find anything on the net. What happened to these packages? How can I add them again?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an alternative that is open source project: https://github.com/Roniasoft/RoniaKit

It contains a variety of components and is well-supported.